# Repeater simulation issues

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm migrating a webforms project to MVC and I've come across a repeater control. The repeater control allows for inline editing (by this I mean each line that can be edited (because there is a criteria to allow this) has input controls on it where you can change the values and an edit button that takes those values and updates the db) as well as display of records displayed in a table.

With the repeater control it's easy to tell which record got updated since when that records edit button is clicked it calls the ItemCommand function passing in the row that was edited allowing me to just get that control name value to get the values. **How is this done in MVC?** I know we have display templates and edit templates but I need to combine them into 1, which I'm able to do with the below code, but if I have more than 1 row that can be edited how do I get the correct row of input controls to get the values?

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Data)
{
    if(item.User == "PIRA" || DateTime.Today != item.EntryDate.Value.Date)
    {
        <tr style="height: 25px;">
            <td hidden="hidden">
                &nbsp;
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TransactionID)
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EntryDate)
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User)
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EffectiveDate)
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RecordType)
            </td>
            <td align="right">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Value)
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Comments)
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                &nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    else
    {
        <tr style="height: 25px;">
            <td hidden="hidden">
                &nbsp;
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TransactionID)
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EntryDate)
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User)
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.EffectiveDate)
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => item.RecordType, Model.RecordTypes)
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Value, new { style = "text-align: right;" })
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Comments, new { cols = 50, @rows = 3 })
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <div style="margin-bottom:10px;">
                    <input type="submit" value="Edit" name="action:Edit" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    @Html.ActionLinkWithList("Delete", "Delete", "Capacity", new { id = item.TransactionID }, null)
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
}
```

Comment: The more I dig in I get the impression I need to not use DisplayFor() and instead make the controls explicit and have the control name have the transaction ID value in it. Then capture the click event for edit in javascript where the transction ID for each edit has the transaction ID passed to it so I can then find each control's value for the record that was clicked and build the right control name using that transaction ID to get the values and then make the call to the controller. Was hoping some technology would do this for me I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this by not using DisplayFor() but instead the control *For() function so I can set the id property (because DisplayFor() doesn't seem to allow this). I set the id to include that records transactionID so each input can be unique. Then each records edit link passes in the transactionID to a javascript function. Then inside there once I have the id I can build the id properties to get all the input values and make my controller call.

ie.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.EffectiveDate, new { id="effectiveDate_" + item.TransactionID, @class="datepicker", style="width: 150px;" })

@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Data", new { onclick = "EditRecord(" + item.TransactionID + ");" })

function EditRecord(id) {

            // get the control values based off the passed in id
            var effDate = $("#effectiveDate_" + id).val();

            // make the call to our controller passing in the edited row data
            $.post("/Data/Edit/", { effectiveDate: effDate });
        }
```

Kind of a pain to do it manually like this but it works. In the web forms repeater control this is probably what it's doing behind the scenes so I wish MVC had something like this as well.